# How to write Queries for retreving, Checking Existence in NHIBERNATE USING(FLUENTNHIBERNATE)

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How to write Queries for retreving, Checking Existence, and all we do in SQL
using NHIBERNATE (FLUENTNHIBERNATE)

Is FluentNhibernate is used in these Queries.

And

**Which one is better Fluent Nhibernate Mapping or XML Mapping**

**Is there any relation or should i know LINQ for learning Nhibernate?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can see several questions:

**"How to write Queries for retreving, Checking Existence"**: see here for the different querylanguages in NH http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/09/nhibernate-queries.html

**"Is FluentNhibernate is used in these Queries"**: **no** FNH is used to configure NHibernate: alternative for hbm.xml and hibernate.cfg

**"Which one is better Fluent Nhibernate Mapping or XML Mapping"**: in most cases FluentNHibernate is much easier to write than xml and covers 95% of options possible in xml. For beginners i would recommend FluentMappings because a lot of sensible defaults make it easier to get something to work.

**"Is there any relation or should i know LINQ for learning Nhibernate?"**: LINQ is one of 6 ways to query in NHibernate. It is an elegant way but neither required nor the "works in all circumstances".

Comment: Thanks for all answers... but You not give answer of mine first Question  How to write Queries for retreving, Checking Existence, and all we do in SQL.

Comment: Sorry sir, i didn't see link attached to your answer. Once Again Thanks a lot